# Core dataで保存する方法が分かりません。

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

Core Dataで保存する方法が分かりません。
プロジェクトはOSXアプリです。XCodeの自動生成のテンプレート使い、Core Dataとバインディングを使ってTable Viewにデータの追加、削除、それを表示するまではできたのですが、保存する方法が分かりません。
なんかmanagedObjectContext saveメソッドを使用するという情報は得たのですが、managedObjectContextが見当たりません。もうアプリ開発は難しすぎます。

環境はOSX10.10.3 XCode6.3.1です。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

プロジェクト生成時に、Use Core Dataに、checkbox入れてれば、AppDelegate.(h|m)に、ありますが。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
ただやはりmanagedObjectContextはありませんでした。
もうほんと難しい、訳わかんない。結局どうしたら保存、読み込みできるんでしょうか？

Comment: 保存できましたが、NSManagedObjectContextは関係ありませんでした。
原因は、Array ControllerのPrepares contentにチェックが付いていなかったためでした。しかしInterface Builderは、細かなミスで鬼のように大量のエラーメッセージ吐き付けられてど叱られるし、エラーメッセージ全く意味不明だし、下手に修正したりするとXCodeのコードと不整合で、やっぱり大量エラーメッセージだし、
ほんとに恐ろしい、難しい訳わかんない。